# JsRender: using if statement comparing values in JSON object to external variable

Tags: javascript, jsrender

In my JsRender template, I want to filter the json object to only render records that meet certain criteria--a parent id, for example, which is a variable that is initialized immediately before executing the render.

What I'd like to do is below, but the second line of syntax is just a guess.  How to do this?

```
<script id="tmpl_report_entry_table_data_rows" type="text/x-jsrender">
{{if ENTRY_ID==n_current_entry_id_from_external_variable}}
<tr class="attribute_data_row">
    <td class="entry_id attribute_data"><span>{{:ENTRY_ID}}</span></td>
    <td class="attribute_1 attribute_data hidden"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__1}}</span></td>
    <td class="attribute_2 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__2}}</span></td>
    <td class="attribute_14 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__14}}</span></td>
    <td class="attribute_13 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__13}}</span></td>
    <td class="attribute_11 attribute_date attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__11}}</span></td>
    <td class="attribute_11 attribute_date_hidden"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__11}}</span></td>
    <td class="attribute_3 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__3}}</span></td>
    <td class="attribute_4 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__4}}</span></td>
    <td class="attribute_5 attribute_data">
        <a href="?"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__5}}</span></a>
    </td>
    <td class="cmd"></td>
</tr>    
{{/if}}
</script>

<script>
var obj_my_data = [
    {"ENTRY_ID":79,
        "test":true,
        "ATTRIBUTE__1":"Aleutian Islands",
        "ATTRIBUTE__2":"Arrowtooth Flounder",
        "ATTRIBUTE__13":"BSAI trawl limited access",
        "ATTRIBUTE__3":"Open",
    "ATTRIBUTE__4":"TAC",
    "ATTRIBUTE__5":"",
    "ATTRIBUTE__11":",",
    "ATTRIBUTE__14":"Entire GOA"},
    {"ENTRY_ID":80,
    "test":true,
    "ATTRIBUTE__1":"Aleutian Islands",
    "ATTRIBUTE__2":"Atka Macherel",
    "ATTRIBUTE__13":"BSAI trawl limited access",
    "ATTRIBUTE__3":"Open",
    "ATTRIBUTE__4":"TAC",
    "ATTRIBUTE__5":"",
    "ATTRIBUTE__11":",",
    "ATTRIBUTE__14":"Entire GOA"}
];

$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("table tbody").append($("#my_template").render(obj_my_data)); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could modify your data to carry your current row ID, it is generally as easy (and cleaner) to 'parameterize' the template, by passing in parameters with the render method. You can do that by passing in an additional context parameter. It can carry both parameters and helper functions that you can pass in dynamically just for this template rendering...

```
$("#my_template").render(myData, {currentRowId: myCurrIdVar}));
```

Then you can access those named parameters from within the template (or within nested templates, too) in the same way as you would access a registered helper - by appending '~' to the name.

```
{{if ENTRY_ID==~currentRowId}}
    ...
{{/if}}
```

I have added a new [sample demo on GitHub](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/12_passing-in-context.html) showing that.

Answer (score 1):

You could just assign the current row value to a property of the data object...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    obj_my_data.currentRow = n_current_entry_id_from_external_variable;
    $("table tbody").append($("#my_template").render(obj_my_data)); 
});
```

Your template can then check against this property.

```
<script id="tmpl_report_entry_table_data_rows" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{if ENTRY_ID == currentRow}}
    // remaining template.
```